# Loading multiple scripts with same variables/functions

Tags: javascript, function

Is it possible to load multiple scripts with same variables/functions in JS, without overriding the old value of the variable. For example to create an own scope/sandbox or object for each loaded script.

Files to load:

script1:

```
<script>
function init() {
    do something...
}
</script>
```

script2:

```
<script>
function init() {
    do something...
}
</script>
```

And after loading call script1.init() or script2.init(), is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could wrap each section of code with a self invoking anonymous function, which will effectively namespace that section.

```
(function() {
    function init() {
        // do something...
     }
})();

init(); // ReferenceError
```

However, if you can't change the code, the second `init` will overwrite the first definition.

However...

> And after loading call script1.init() or script2.init(), is this possible?

...is confusing. Do you already have the `init()` as methods of an object? If so, they *won't* overwrite each other.

Comment: I want to load the code from any source server, and create an object which should prevent the code from overwriting, but the code I want to load is not changable.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no.  There is a single global scope on a single page.

However, by using something like the module pattern, you can make a fake namespace:

For example:

```
var script1 = (function() {
    var that = {};
    that.init = function() { 
      do something...
    };

    more functions...

    return that;
})();
```

And then call it by using script1.init();

You can find out more about the module pattern [here](http://www.klauskomenda.com/code/javascript-programming-patterns/#modulehttp://).

Comment: The problem is that I want to write a site and the user could add his/her own plugins to the site, the code for the plugin is loaded from any source, but I don't want to load the code in an iframe. The problem with your solution is that the users have to write their code in a given design pattern, but I want them to let them write the code in the way they want.

Comment: In that case you might want to research how sites such as jsfiddle implement sandboxing.